# In which RFC is =xx notation defined?

Tags: html, content-encoding

For form/multipart-data, I've seen input that has the form =[2 to 6 hex chars].
I'm wondering which RFC defines it?
I want to encode non-file form data to a binary char stream so that iconv doesn't produce bad output. I reckon the behavior is similar to formurl-encoded decoding.

Comment: I believe that when files are part of the stream, base64 encoding is usually involved (as well? in addition to? other?).

Comment: It's not base64. It's like urlencoded, but with = instead of % and the ability to have 2-6 trailing hex chars (as opposed to just 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multipart/form-data` is based on [RFC 2045](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt) and [RFC 2046](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt), formalized in [RFC 2388](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt), and included in W3C standards [HTML40](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) Section 13.4 and [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#multipart-form-data) Section 4.10.22.6.  The encoding you are seeing is MIME's `quoted-printable` encoding, which is defined in [RFC 2045](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt) Section 6.7.  The `quoted-printable` encoding operates on byte octets, and thus will ALWAYS contain 2 hex characters after a `=` character (except for "soft" line breaks, which consist of a `=` character followed by a CRLF line break).

Comment: `Quoted-printable`: That's what I was looking for.